# Unable to install php 5.6 in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10

I don't know this is a right platform to ask this question or not but am tired of trying everything available on google to install php 5.6 on ubuntu 16.10.

I have added ppa :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php; 
sudo apt-get update;
```

then i have tried :

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6;
```

and it keep giving me this result :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5.6-json' for regex 'php5.6'
Note, selecting 'php5.6-common' for regex 'php5.6'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

Please help me...!!

Comment: 16.10 is now out of support, so you'll need to install 17.04 or 16.04 (or 14.04). Package management will be broken on unsupported releases, so trying to install anything is likely to be problematic.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Can you confirm that 17.04 supports php 5.6 or not..??

Comment: on 17.04 if I add the ondrej PPA I can install php5.6

Comment: @Zanna post your comment as answer.. it worked for me.. i have updated to 17.04 and everything is working perfectly fine..!! Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: It'll help to lots of users like me..!!

Comment: That's awesome that it worked for you, but there's no need for an extra answer I think - see [Installing PHP 5.6 on Xenial (16.04)](//askubuntu.com/q/756181) - but you can leave a comment on the answer to say it works on 17.04 too, that may be helpful. 16.10 is off-topic, so this question will be closed, but I have upvoted it so people can find the comments and links

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer given by @Zanna :

16.10 is now out of support, so you'll need to install 17.04 or 16.04 (or 14.04). Package management will be broken on unsupported releases, so trying to install anything is likely to be problematic.

In 17.04, it works perfectly fine..!!